# Get FirebaseAuthPlatform for Flutter web RecaptchaVerifier

Tags: firebase-authentication, flutter-web

**SITUATION:**
I'm in the process of implementing Firebase phone sign-in on flutter web. In doing so, I want to customize the reCAPTCHA that is called by the signInWithPhoneNumber function as outlined in the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/phone-auth#web_signinwithphonenumber).

```dart
final ConfirmationResult confirmationResult = await auth.signInWithPhoneNumber(
  phoneNumber, verifier_should_go_here
);
```

**COMPLICATION:**
I am trying to implement the [RecaptchaVerifier](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/RecaptchaVerifier-class.html), but it has a required parameter called [FirebaseAuthPlatform](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth_platform_interface/latest/firebase_auth_platform_interface/FirebaseAuthPlatform-class.html), and I can't figure out how to generate this parameter for my app.

**QUESTION:**
How can I create a RecaptchaVerifier to pass to the signInWithPhoneNumber function on flutter web?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

3 easy steps:

- You add the `firebase_auth_platform_interface` dependency to your `pubspec.yaml` file with `flutter pub add firebase_auth_platform_interface`
- You import the package like this: `import 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/firebase_auth_platform_interface.dart' show FirebaseAuthPlatform;`
- Inside the constructor for `RecaptchaVerifier`, you use `FirebaseAuthPlatform.instance`

Answer (score 3):

You have two ways:

1. Use this import (it's included in "firebase_auth"):

```
import 'package:firebase_auth_web/firebase_auth_web.dart';

RecaptchaVerifier(
  auth: FirebaseAuthWeb.instance
)
```

2. Use the package "firebase_auth_oauth_platform_interface"

```
import 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/firebase_auth_platform_interface.dart';

RecaptchaVerifier(
  auth: FirebaseAuthPlatform.instance
)
```